# does google tracker detect python requests?

Tags: python, google-analytics, python-requests

if I send a really huge number of requests thru python for scrapping more than 1.5 million data from a website that has a google tracker, does google track this traffic? can the website owner reverse the request to detect who am I even though I'm using VPN?
any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: Everything you do on the web is trackable. Please don't ask questions about how to bypass security measures, that's for a hacking site, not for a programming site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question about bypassing web server limits and hiding fetch activity, and not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on whether you render the responses.

If you only fetch the body and don't render/execute JS in it, then you won't trigger any JS libraries loaded to the page, that would include any front-end driven analytics.

That said, however, there's still backend (the web server) where each of your requests will likely be logged, including ip, useragent, referrer and about twenty more dimensions, potentially.

Short answer: yes, if the owner makes a real effort, theoretically, it is possible to get to you even if you use VPN. To be honest, VPN is a very poor tool to hide your identity/ip. Mostly it only helps with trivial scripted detections. You want to read more on digital forensics before doing anything inappropriate online. It will quickly show how many great ways there are to find a person on the web.